# Rearranging a huge list In Notepad++ replace feature

Tags: notepad++

I remember doing this in notepad++ few years back. I think it was a plugin i believe.

I have a list like this

```
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
```

and i need it to be reorder like this

```
["12345", "123456", "1234567", "12345678"]

How is this done on notepad++? Its an extremely huge list and doing this one by one will take ages.
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 steps.

1. add double quotes and comma and `[` & `]`

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
   - Find what: `(\A)?^(.+)$(\z)?`
   - Replace with: `(?1[)"$2"(?3]:,)`
   - **CHECK** *Wrap around*
   - **CHECK** *Regular expression*
   - **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
   - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\A)?       # optional group 1, beginning of file
^           # beginning of line
  (.+)      # group 2,1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
(\z)?       # optional group 3, end of file
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1[)       # if group 1 exists, add [
"$2"        # content of group 2 suround by quotes
(?3         # if group 3 exists
    ]         # add ]
  :         # else
    ,         add a comma
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

2. join the lines

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>   (select all)
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>   (join the lines)

**Screenshot final:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Worked perfect.

Comment: @AnthonyFranco: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)